# What does <T> in javascript for?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

eg. a sample code from React source code

```
export function useState<S>(initialState: (() => S) | S) {
  const dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
  return dispatcher.useState(initialState);
}
```

what does `<s>` here means?

Comment: This is likely not Javascript code, but Typescript code. Is this a `.ts` file? This sounds like Typescript generics. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: No, it is .js file https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js

Comment: Given we're talking about the react source, I'd wager it's flow: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/

Comment: It's flow ;) https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L7

Comment: Aha! Good call.

Comment: Oh, I see... but how could js write in this way function<>()? Won't it through a syntax error?! I haven't seen it in MSDN tho.

Comment: If I had any amount of confidence in what that syntax was trying accomplish, I'd write an answer. But unfortunately I'd just have to read the - _maybe_ related - documentation for generics. Either way, I'd bet dollars to donuts that a transpiler (babel) is involved. I'm fairly sure that syntax isn't part of ECMAScript.

Comment: Ha, you are right, it would be error on dev tool, thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [generic flow type annotation](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/). It gets added to the code to be able to spot type missmatches using the IDE.  During compile time, these annotations get removed (as they are invalid JS).

This annotation basically means that you can `useState` with any type you want, and you could also pass an initializer function that returns a certain type:

```
  useState("test") // T is string
  useState(1) // T is number
  useState(() => 1) // T is number
```